# SELECT FROM table,ORDER BY IF(...)

Tags: mysql

My table

```
SELECT * FROM mail;
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| t                   | srcuser | srchost | dstuser | dsthost | size    |
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 2014-05-11 10:15:08 | barb    | saturn  | tricia  | mars    |   58274 |
| 2014-05-12 12:48:13 | tricia  | mars    | gene    | venus   |  194925 |
| 2014-05-12 15:02:49 | phil    | mars    | phil    | saturn  |    1048 |
| 2014-05-12 18:59:18 | barb    | saturn  | tricia  | venus   |     271 |
| 2014-05-14 09:31:37 | gene    | venus   | barb    | mars    |    2291 |
| 2014-05-14 11:52:17 | phil    | mars    | tricia  | saturn  |    5781 |
| 2014-05-14 14:42:21 | barb    | venus   | barb    | venus   |   98151 |
| 2014-05-14 17:03:01 | tricia  | saturn  | phil    | venus   | 2394482 |
| 2014-05-15 07:17:48 | gene    | mars    | gene    | saturn  |    3824 |
| 2014-05-15 08:50:57 | phil    | venus   | phil    | venus   |     978 |
| 2014-05-15 10:25:52 | gene    | mars    | tricia  | saturn  |  998532 |
| 2014-05-15 17:35:31 | gene    | saturn  | gene    | mars    |    3856 |
| 2014-05-16 09:00:28 | gene    | venus   | barb    | mars    |     613 |
| 2014-05-16 23:04:19 | phil    | venus   | barb    | venus   |   10294 |
| 2014-05-19 12:49:23 | phil    | mars    | tricia  | saturn  |     873 |
| 2014-05-19 22:21:51 | gene    | saturn  | gene    | venus   |   23992 |
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I have query like this

```
 SELECT t, srcuser, dstuser, size
    -> FROM mail
    -> ORDER BY IF(srcuser='phil',0,1), srcuser, dstuser;
```

which will produce

```
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| t                   | srcuser | dstuser | size    |
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| 2014-05-16 23:04:19 | phil    | barb    |   10294 |
| 2014-05-12 15:02:49 | phil    | phil    |    1048 |
| 2014-05-15 08:50:57 | phil    | phil    |     978 |
| 2014-05-14 11:52:17 | phil    | tricia  |    5781 |
| 2014-05-19 12:49:23 | phil    | tricia  |     873 |
| 2014-05-14 14:42:21 | barb    | barb    |   98151 |
| 2014-05-11 10:15:08 | barb    | tricia  |   58274 |
| 2014-05-12 18:59:18 | barb    | tricia  |     271 |
| 2014-05-14 09:31:37 | gene    | barb    |    2291 |
| 2014-05-16 09:00:28 | gene    | barb    |     613 |
| 2014-05-15 07:17:48 | gene    | gene    |    3824 |
| 2014-05-15 17:35:31 | gene    | gene    |    3856 |
| 2014-05-19 22:21:51 | gene    | gene    |   23992 |
| 2014-05-15 10:25:52 | gene    | tricia  |  998532 |
| 2014-05-12 12:48:13 | tricia  | gene    |  194925 |
| 2014-05-14 17:03:01 | tricia  | phil    | 2394482 |
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I do not understand how order is imposed.OK, phil is name of interest.Book says,suppose that you want to sort mail table messages in sender/recipient
order, but you want to put messages for a particular sender first. Why do we use 0,1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine the following `ORDER BY IF(srcuser='phil',0,1), srcuser, dstuser;`

We know what `ORDER BY` does, so I'll ignore that other than to say it orders the fields in the listed sequence.

`IF(srcuser='phil',0,1)`
If the user is 'phil', we assign a value of 0 to a temporary ordering field, otherwise we assign the value 1.  As this is the first field, and `ORDER BY` defaults to ascending if not explicitly stated, we order first by that temporary field.  Any item with a 0 will be first (the phil's) and anything with a 1 will be after that (all others).

The other fields are then sorted to give you the order you output your results set.

Basically, the 0,1 is to help create an order to sort items where they would otherwise be at a different point in a list.  You could change the values to `2,5` and get the same result.

Ultimately, it's actually saying `IF(srcuser='phil',x,y)`, where `x < y`.  If you wanted to change the order so it was descending for the other fields, you'd use `ORDER BY IF(srcuser='phil',x,y)... DESC` where `x > y`.

Another reason for using 0 and 1 is that they are numbers, and numbers are easier to sort that letters (computationally).  The same result could be achieved by using `IF(srcuser='phil','a','b')`

Answer (score 2):

0 is less than 1 so doing "0, 1" ensures that the item you want comes first. The IF statement returns either 0 or 1 for the ORDER BY wrapped around it.

Comment: Does that mean I could put '0,2'?

Comment: Yes I believe so, or "1, 2" if that makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

What MySQL does when ordering by a field, is that it will try to sort the field's values in ascending order.

In your case you need to sort `mail` with `srcuser='phil'` first, so you need to add a "virtual" value to do that because otherwise the `mail` will get sorted by `srcuser` (by name), so `phil` is going to be ranked lower.

So what it does, is that it makes messages sent by `phil` have a lower value (so that in ASC order they'll be ordered first) and then assign the same value (`1`) to the rest of the entries so that they get ordered by the rest of the `ORDER BY` clause (`srcuser, dstuser`)